# Solving a regularized linear least squares problem using only matrix-vector products $Ax$ and $A^Tx$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

I'm working on an application that involves solving a regularized linear least squares problem of the form

\begin{align}
\min_x \frac{1}{2} \| y - Ax\|_2^2 + \frac{\mu}{2} \| x - b \|_2^2,  \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}

where $\mu>0$ is given. Naturally, $(\star)$ could be solved analytically with

\begin{align}
\hat{x} &= (A^T A + \mu I)^{-1} (A^T y + \mu b),
\end{align}

but unfortunately, I don't have direct access to $A$, since its construction is very complicated and very demanding in terms of memory consumption. Instead of that, I have a black-box algorithmic procedure that computes the matrix-vector products $Ax$ and $A^Tx$ very efficiently. What are some examples of simple iterative procedures I could use to solve $(\star)$ at least approximately?

Comment: Have you considered the conjugate gradient algorithm?

Comment: Not yet! how could I derive it for my problem?

Comment: First, formulate your problem as $\min_x \frac{1}{2} x^TQx + p^Tx$, then solve iteratively as
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{g_k^Td_k}{d_k^TQd_k}d_k,
$$
where $g_k=Qx_k + p$, $d_0=-g_0$, and $d_{k+1} = \frac{g_{k+1}^TQd_k}{d_k^TQd_k} - g_{k+1}.$ You may stop whenever $g_k = 0$ for some $k$. The method converges in at most $n$ steps, where $n$ is the dimension of $x$.

Comment: thank you! I think it actually worked, but I used wikipedia's algorithm which is similar to yours! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_resulting_algorithm

Comment: Good to hear! :)

Comment: FYI, there are several ways you can calculate the $\beta_k$ parameter. The one I gave, and in Wikipedia, are naive. Other formulas are used in practice, such as Fletcher-Reeves, Polyak-Ribiere, Hager-Zhang, etc. You can also consider the MINRES algo.

Comment: That's very interesting stuff! thank you again!